# Large amount of PDF generation in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, report

We are generating pdf based report cards for our clients on a php based ERP platform. They want to be able to generate around 2000 report cards one pdf file as seperate pages.

We have done this successfully using an HTML to PDF converter called DomPDF. However the script is too heavy and takes about an hour to complete and sometimes breaks, which is unacceptable. They currently used a desktop based software which delivers the report cards instantly via Crystal Reports.

In PHP we were wondering how we could generate such a large number of PDF pages (2000) with a much a higher speed.(hopefully less than 10 seconds).

Any suggestions for this would be welcome.

The server is running on Linux Ubuntu, we dont mind using a solution that involves use of exec.

Comment: Have you tried using one of the many PDF generation libraries that allows you to write straight to PDF, without HTML?

Comment: I don't think so 2000 pages will be generate in `10 seconds`. It will take time.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar It's certainly possible to do it within seconds or fractions of a second. You just need to generate Postscript for some 2000 pages. Roughly comparable to generating an HTML table with many thousand rows, which doesn't have to take any time at all either.

Comment: @user I have used [TCPDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCPDF) before, which I think should be able to handle it speed-wise. It has a pretty awful API, but otherwise works. Google for some similar libraries and you shall find something that fits you.

Answer (score 1):

Using WKHTMLTOPDF to generate a PDF report with between 450 and 500 pages(2 MB text only) takes 30 to 50 seconds,
while the same amount of data in TCPDF or HTMLTOPDF or DOMPDF takes between 5 and 8 mins

Answer (score 0):

We have been using [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)-utility that does quite a good job, but I'm not sure it's the fastest one out there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate the PDFs from HTML, I would recommend using [WKHTMLTOPDF](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) via exec() or system(). We're using it in some applications and haven't had any problems at all so far (but neither do we generate the same amount of data as you guys).

Answer (score 0):

Or Maybe Try the i-report designer. I had used it once and its great but you need to read forums or tutorials for customization and one thing about this is its an Open source, hope it would help you.

http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer